# Potential resource leak: 'client' may not be closed at this location

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using `HttpClient`, but in Eclipse I'm getting warning *"Potential resource leak"*. When I use try-resource `ClosableHttpClient`, I get an error *"Connection pool shutdown"*. Any suggestion how I can fix the potential leak?

```
public void patchOrder(final OmtOrder order) throws ApiException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId("system");
        final String url = order + "/order";
        EntityRequest<OmtOrder> requestEntity = new EntityRequest<>();
        requestEntity.setEntity(order);
        requestEntity.setUser(user);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));
    
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        final HttpEntity<EntityRequest<OmtOrder>> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestEntity, headers);
        try {
            restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PATCH, requestHttpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<PayloadResponse<OmtOrder>>() {
            });
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw ApiException.createFrom(ResponseCode.SERVICE_NOT_REACHABLE, e.getMessage());
        }
    
    }
```

When I use try-resource, I get *"Connection pool shutdown"*:

```
try(CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()){
 }
```

Comment: What does the code look like with try-resource? Did you try adding a finally block that calls `client.close()`?

Comment: i dont have option client.close() and for try-resource its same code just this part
try(CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()){
......
 }

Comment: If you replace HttpClient in the question with CloseableHttpClient, you should have a close method

Comment: but i will still get  warning Potential leak

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but on which line, of the code in your question, does Eclipse indicate the _Potential resource leak_ warning?

Comment: on last one :  throw ApiException.createFrom(ResponseCode.SERVICE_NOT_REACHABLE, e.getMessage());

Comment: Do you have `restTemplate.setRequestFactory` method inside that try block, or after?

Comment: @OneCricketeer In a try-with-resource, Java calls close for you, so you don't need a finally block with that calls `client.close()`.

Comment: @Mark I understand that. The question obviously isn't using try with resources since there was a separate error

Comment: @OneCricketeer maybe i didnt explain good... i want to use try-with-resource but problem is when after this CloseableHttpClient  call other rest api, to do another logic then i get connection pool problem.

Comment: Sounds like your problem exists in the restTemplate, then. In other words, you've got one of those, then assign a client to it, which you closed, so it cannot be used again. You'll need to again create a new client and call setRequestFactory with that

Answer (score 0):

Does this makes any difference in Eclipse warnings?

```
public void patchOrder(final OmtOrder order) throws ApiException {
   ... clip ...  
   CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
   try {
      restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      final HttpEntity<EntityRequest<OmtOrder>> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestEntity, headers);
      restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PATCH, requestHttpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<PayloadResponse<OmtOrder>>() {
      });
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw ApiException.createFrom(ResponseCode.SERVICE_NOT_REACHABLE, ex.getMessage());
   }  finally {
      client.close();
   }
}
```